# Not able to perform Insert operation

Tags: sql-server-2008

My new table is

```
create table #Det_rec(
C_ID varchar(16),
Allot_Quan decimal(12,3),
LocIn_Allot_Quan decimal(12,3),
LRC smallint default 00,
LocIn_R varchar(50) DEFAULT '      ',
LocIn_Date datetime default '   ',
Filler numeric(8) default '   ',
RTA_Ref_No varchar(8) default'CDSL----',
isin_opt varchar(10))
```

while doing insert operation

```
INSERT INTO #Det_rec (C_ID,Allot_Quan,isin_opt)
select 
t.credit_dpclid,
cast(t.qty as decimal(12,3)),
t.isin_opt 
from fin_mst f inner join #temps t on f.IHNO = t.IHNO
```

I got an error like

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I have applied convert cast functions, but still I am getting this error.

Comment: can you add your #temps table qty column data here or complete #temp table here? @soundx

Comment: You have some *odd* choices of defaults there - Look at `Filler` and then run `select CAST('   ' as numeric(8))`

Comment: Have you run just the select statement and actually looked at the values you're trying to insert? Failing that, it's one of the values your not trying to insert (hint - look at the defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, since any one of the quantity value might be a string.

```
CREATE TABLE #Det_rec
  (
     C_ID             VARCHAR(16),
     Allot_Quan       DECIMAL(12, 3),
     LocIn_Allot_Quan DECIMAL(12, 3),
     LRC              SMALLINT DEFAULT 00,
     LocIn_R          VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '      ',
     LocIn_Date       DATETIME DEFAULT '   ',
     Filler           NUMERIC(8) DEFAULT '   ',
     RTA_Ref_No       VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT'CDSL----',
     isin_opt         VARCHAR(10)
  )

INSERT INTO #Det_rec
            (C_ID,
             Allot_Quan,
             isin_opt)
SELECT t.credit_dpclid,
       cast(t.qty AS DECIMAL(12, 3)),
       t.isin_opt
FROM   fin_mst f
       INNER JOIN #temps t
               ON f.IHNO = t.IHNO
WHERE  isnumeric(t.qty) = 1
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is *no* guarantee that a value can be cast to e.g. `DECIMAL(12,3)`. E.g. `'£'` passes the `ISNUMERIC` test, but will still cause an error.

Comment: @Damien: You are right, let sonudx to check with this code, if he still face the issue then please suggest for new solution.